# can't find the error

Tags: class, field

I'm having error in main can anyone help me find where the bug is ? I'm trying to create a class and use setter/getter to set each field where eventually I will test this class it to make sure the fields work

```
public class College{

    public class person{

        private String name;
        private int age;
        private double id; 
        //constructor to set fields 
        public Schedule (String name, int age, double id){
             this.name= name;
             this.age= age;
             this.id= id;
        }

        public String getName(){
            return this.name;
        }

        public void setName(String Name) {
            this.name= name;
        }
        public int getAge(){
            return  this.Age;
        }

        public void setAge(int age) {
            this.age = age;
        }
        public double getId(){
            return this.id;
        }

        public void setId(double id) {
            this.id = id;
        }


    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        Schedule Per1= new College("John", 2,2.0);



    }


}
```

Comment: You need to show the code from main where you try to instantiate/manipulate the class.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might want to read about how to create class properly.
The link below would help you (in C#):

> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9afc042.aspx

```
public class person{

    private String name;
    private int age;
    private double id; 
    //constructor to set fields 
    public person(String name, int age, double id){
         this.name= name;
         this.age= age;
         this.id= id;
    }

    public String getName(){
        return this.name;
    }

    public void setName(String Name) {
        this.name= name;
    }
    public int getAge(){
        return  this.Age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }
    public double getId(){
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(double id) {
        this.id = id;
    }


}

public static void main(String[] args) {


    person Per1= new person("John", 2,2.0);



}
```